# Can't get data from JSON array

Tags: php, arrays, json

Trying to learn JSON. Doing some simple exercises, but can't get past this one. I've rewatched the tutorial about 30 times. Any pointers?

here's the JSON:

```
{
  "name": "Username",
  "profile_name": "profile_username",
  "profile_url": "http://myapi.net/profile_username"
  "courses": [
    { "name": "English 340" },
    { "name": "History 202" },
    { "name": "Underwater Basket Weaving" }
  ]
}
```

It's in a variable called $JSON_array, and here's the foreach loop I'm trying to use to pull the course names out and put then in an unordered list.

```
<ul>
  <?php for( $i = 0; $i < count($JSON_array->courses); $i++ ): ?>
    echo '<li>';
    echo $JSON_array->{'courses'}[$i]->{'name'};
    echo '</li>';  
  <?php endfor; ?>
</ul>
```

Tis not doing anything... My source code shows empty list items

Comment: `var_dump($JSON_array)`

Comment: you are using `for` loop. use `foreach` will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are missing `,` after profile_url

```
$json = '{
  "name": "Username",
  "profile_name": "profile_username",
  "profile_url": "http://myapi.net/profile_username",
  "courses": [
    { "name": "English 340" },
    { "name": "History 202" },
    { "name": "Underwater Basket Weaving" }
  ]
}';



$arr = json_decode($json);
?>

<ul>
  <?php for( $i = 0; $i < count($arr->courses); $i++ ): 
    echo '<li>';
    echo $arr->{'courses'}[$i]->{'name'};
    echo '</li>';  
  endfor; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: ERMAGHERD!!! I was about to rip my shorthairs out! I rewrote that echo line about a billion times! It was the stupid JSON I was using for this exercise that was breaking the function!

Comment: yes it happens some times! 

If you got me right you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$json = '{"name": "Username","profile_name": "profile_username","profile_url": "http://myapi.net/profile_username",
"courses": [
    { "name": "English 340" },
    { "name": "History 202" },
    { "name": "Underwater Basket Weaving" }
  ]
}';//comma was missing after profile_url

$arr = json_decode($json,true);//encode as an associative array

<ul>
 <?php
  foreach($arr['courses'] as $course){
    echo '<li>';
    echo $course['name'];
    echo '</li>';  
  }
 ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($JSON_array->courses as $course): ?>
        echo '<li>';
        echo $course->name;
        echo '</li>';  
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Updated:
Moreover, your JSON is invalid!!
`"profile_url": "http://myapi.net/profile_username"`
you missing comma at the end of this line